# Associate shape with color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

In Illustrator you can create own colors in the color palette (as you might know :)). Now I want to do the following: create a shape, for example a rectangle, and assign a color from the palette. Is it possible to change the color of every shape I assigned the color the when I change the color in the palette? For example I create a color "myColor", assign it to three rectangles and when I change the "myColor" in the palette, all the three rectangles are updated automatically. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the new swatch, check the Global checkbox in the New Swatch dialog. Any change you make to the swatch will then replicate anywhere you use it.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for!